# want to make list with vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to display a list from an array of data, but I get an error: `cannot read property 'name' of undefined`.

**HTML**

```
<div id="list">
  <myitems v-for="item in list" v-bind:my="item">
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var items = Vue.component('myitems', {
  props: ['my'],
  template: `<li>{{my.name}} {{my.age}}</li>`
});

new items({
  data: {
    list: [
      {name: 'myName', age: 25}
    ]
  }
}).$mount("#list");
```

I think I can't match `item in list` and props `my` but I'm unsure of what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in your html. The `<myitems>` tag should be inside the scope of the `v-for` directive, so it should not be declared on the `<myitems>` tag. Try something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="list" v-for="item in list" >
  <myitems  v-bind:my="item"></myitems>
</div>
```

Comment: so sorry my comment was for Daniel's answer

Comment: No problem, tell me if you have any question

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there are many issues in your code.

First thing - you have not defined the root Vue instance, should be like this:

```
new Vue({
  data: {
    list: [
      {name: 'myName', age: 25}
    ]
  }
}).$mount("#list");
```

Your component registation is good, keep It like that:

```
var items = Vue.component('myitems', {
  props: ['my'],
  template: `<li>{{my.name}} {{my.age}}</li>`
});
```

And you forgot to wrap your component into the `ul` since template returns a `li`

```
<div id="list">
  <ul>
    <myitems v-for="item in list" v-bind:my="item"></myitems>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/am5Ldp9k/

Comment: Thanks I have a question. if I want to use multiple Component in a page and different root., what can I do? that code also for multiple components using.

Comment: @burningwebfuel sorry but could you please clarify your question ?

Comment: my question was for Daniel's answer and I totally understood my mistake. self solved silly problem. I misunderstood that I could use only one `new Vue` in one page.

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues in your code. First of all, you don't need to assign a variable to Vue components that you register. They will simply be available to you after you register them with `Vue.component`:

```
Vue.component('myitems', {
  props: ['my'],
  template: '<li>{{my.name}} {{my.age}}</li>'
});
```

Second, you need a root component. You can do this by calling `new Vue()`:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#list',
  data: {
    list: [{ name: 'myName', age: 25 }]
  }
});
```

You need to pass in an element ID/class to serve as the root element, and any data you want to pass down to the child elements. Once you do this, it should work properly. Here's a jsfiddle for a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/coligo/49gptnad/